# I am receiving HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required error

Tags: authentication, proxy, ntlm

I know there are already a lot of questions about this particular error but my problem seems slightly unique.

I only receive HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required a portion of the time (20% maybe) while the majority of the time it works perfectly.  I was wondering if anyone could think of a reason that my program running under my authentication would throw that error so inconsistently?

Full command prompt error minus stack trace:

```
Jun12, 2012 1:49:01 PM org. apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication process
SEVER: Proxy authentication error: Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication: org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
```

Answer (score 0):

your web browser might be authenticating you, and that authentication might stay valid for a short period of time when you run your program. Alternatively, there may be multiple proxies and some of the time, you hit a proxy that you have not previously authenticated with.